# IAM roles for least-privilege service account to deploy firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, service-accounts, google-iam

Is there documentation on the correct set of IAM roles to assign to a deploying service account for firebase, short of the overly-broad "Editor" role?

Further context:

I have a firebase app deploying from a CI provider. I provide service account credentials to the provider in their GUI, saved as an environment variable. This works fine for deployment.

However, because I have to share the credentials with the CI provider, I'd like that service account to have the least necessary privileges. I have only had success using the default service account (which the firebase docs recommend) which has the "Editor" role over the whole project. This seems overly broad to me.

Every other attempt has run into some kind of permission error. Most recently one of the firebase functions that I deployed was unable to connect to my database, despite my best attempt at making sure the service account had the appropriate database access role. I'd rather not spend days guessing and checking what roles are needed. Looking for documentation.

Comment: You may check this documentation: [Firebase IAM Permissions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/permissions) and [Examples of role recommendations](https://cloud.google.com/policy-intelligence/docs/role-recommendations-overview#examples)